# Functions that are compatible with equivalence relations over its domain and codomain

Tags: reference-request, functions, equivalence-relations

Given a function $f : X \to Y$, an equivalence relation $\sim_X$ on $X$ and an equivalence relation $\sim_Y$ on $Y$, there is a notion of ``compatibility'' between $f$, $\sim_X$ and $\sim_Y$ if the following holds: $x_0 \mathbin{\sim_X} x_1 \implies f(x_0) \mathbin{\sim_Y} f(x_1)$. If it holds, we can define a quotient over $f$ as the function $f/(\sim_X, \sim_Y) : X/{\sim_X} \to Y/{\sim_Y}$ that maps each $E \in X/{\sim_X}$ to the unique element of $Y/{\sim_Y}$ that contains $f(E)$.

Is this notion (of compatibility and quotient of functions) already well-studied, and is there a proper term for this ``compatibility''? Perhaps $f$ is some kind of homomorphism...

In the special case where ${\sim_X} = {\sim_Y}$ and $X = Y$, we can say that $\sim_X$ is a *congruence relation* that is invariant under $f$.

**Update**: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation#Well-definedness_under_an_equivalence_relation) calls such an $f$ a *morphism* from $\sim_X$ to $\sim_Y$. However, as I am using this concept together with other categories and morphisms, such terminology can be confusing. Is there a standard name for the category $\mathbf{C}$ of equivalence relations (or partitions, I suppose) and such morphisms between them, so I can state without ambiguity that $f \in \hom_\mathbf{C}({\sim_X}, {\sim_Y})$?

Answer (score 1):

See, for example, [page 118](http://books.google.com/books?id=IL-SI67hjI4C&lpg=PA119&ots=nbgmDfdiKE&dq=mappings%20that%20respect%20equivalence%20relations&pg=PA118#v=onepage&q&f=false) of Bourbaki's "Theory of Sets Volume 1."

Comment: Thanks for the reference, but doesn't it only account for the $\sim_X$ part?